# Error message on modal from codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've made a form on a modal dialog to insert into a database

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Crear nueva clase</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
                    <?php echo form_open('clase/create');?>  
                    <form class="form col-md-12 center-block">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg"  id="name" name="name" placeholder="Nombre"/>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                             <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="info" name="info" placeholder="Información"/>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <button typ="submit"class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">Crear</button>
                          </div>
                        </form>

                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Works  but the error messages when the validation is not passed are not shown in nowhere

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Clase extends CI_Controller {

 function __construct()
 {
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->model('clase_model','',TRUE);
   $this->load->helper(array('form'));
 }

 function index()
 {
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
        $data['title'] = 'Gestión de Clases';
        $data['clases'] = $this->clase_model->getAll();
      $this->load->view('header', $data);
      $this->load->view('clase_view', $data);

     }
     else{

          redirect('login', 'refresh');
     }
 }

 function create(){
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
      $this->load->library('form_validation');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Nombre', 'trim|min_length[2]|required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('info', 'Información', 'trim');

       if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
          $data['clases'] = $this->clase_model->getAll();
          $this->load->view('header', $data);
          $this->load->view('clase_view', $data);
       }
       else{
          if($this->input->post('info')){
             $this->insert2($this->input->post('name'),$this->input->post('info'));
          }
          else{
            $this->insert1($this->input->post('name')); 
          }
       }   
    }
    else{
          redirect('login', 'refresh');
    }
 }

 function insert2($name,$information){
    $dat = array(
      'nombre'=>$name,
      'info'=>$information
    );
    $this-> db ->insert('clase',$dat);

    echo $name;
    redirect('clase', 'refresh');
 }
 function insert1($name){
    $dat = array(
      'nombre'=>$name,
    );

    $this-> db ->insert('clase',$dat);
    redirect('clase', 'refresh');
 }
}
?>
```

The create method works correct in any case but I need to see the valifdation error messages,how I can do it??

Comment: If there's an error, do they show in the modal on the page?

Comment: The error is not shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show your error message on the modal then you should submit your form via ajax.And from controller function echo your error message using json_encode function. Such like-

```
    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
        $data = array('error_message' => form_error('input_name'));
        echo json_encode($data);
        }
```

And using jQuery do this-

```
        $(document).on("click", ".btn", function () {
             $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "your/url",
                    data: {your:data},
                    success: function(data) {

   //and from data parse your json data and show error message in the modal
                    var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                        if(obj!=null)
                            {                             
                                $('#err_mssg').html(obj['error_message']);
                            }
                    }});
                 });
```

Comment: Good solution,but I'm using codeigniter and I don't know how to get the error messages to store it

Comment: see my edited answer, i showed there how to do that.